# How to redirect folder request to a subfolder with htaccess and GREP

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have about 200 folders that contain pdfs and docs. They should all be redirected to a subfolder in the same directory. There are also folders and files in the same directory that should not.

The folders all have the same name-structure (123-name-name with - or _ mixed) which match the following with GREP in BBEdit:
`(\d{3}(_|-).+)`

So I tried something like:
`RedirectMatch 302 ^/([\d{3}(_|-).+)]/(.*)/?$ /subfolder/$2`
placed in the same folder as the ones I want to redirect.
I have no idea how to set the match correctly.

A URL like example.com/images/123-name-name/somefile.pdf (or doc, docx) should be found at example.com/images/subfolder/123-name-name/somefile.pdf

But the code above results in a Internal Server Error.

It would be great if someone could help me in that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
^(.*?\/\d{3}(?:-|_)\w+(?:-|_)\w+\/)(.*)$
```

to capture both parts of the url in capture groups, and replace with `$1kunden/$2`, so your line will look like:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^(.*?\/\d{3}(?:-|_)\w+(?:-|_)\w+\/)(.*)$ $1kunden/$2
```

This would insert `kunden/` in between the rest of the url and the file name.

If you want to specify that the filename must have an extension (ie, include at least 1 `.`) you could replace the regex with:

```
^(.*?\/\d{3}(?:-|_)\w+(?:-|_)\w+\/)(.*?\..*?)$
```

**EDIT** My bad, to prevent the recursion, you can use a negative look-ahead to ensure the subfolder doesn't already exist in the path:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^((?!.*subfolder\/).*?\/)(\d{3}(?:-|_)\w+(?:-|_)\w+\/)(.*)$ $1subfolder/$2$3
```

This will prevent a url that already contains `subfolder/` from redirecting again.

Comment: Great! That helped me a lot. I just had to alter the order a little because I need example.com/images/subfolder/123-name-name ... So my result is:
`RedirectMatch 302 ^(.*?\/)(\d{3}(?:-|_)\w+(?:-|_)\w+\/)(.*)$ $1subfolder/$2$3`
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm ... tested now on a real server and got an error because of an endless execution of the code. Result of Redirect is `/images/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/112-Name-Name/full-path.txt`. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Hurrah! Works fine! You cannot imaging how this helps in my case. And ... ah ... I now see why the redirect is recurrent ... I had no idea about this before. Thanks again!